# Экспорт/импорт из одной базы в другую

Tags: mysql

Вот есть у меня две таблицы, одна на хосте, другая на локалке. Во вторую (на локалке) я добавляю новые столбцы, при попытке импорта этой таблицы на хост возникает такая ошибка:

> #1054 - Неизвестный столбец 'new' в 'field list'

Структура первой таблицы (в которую импортирую)

```
--
-- Структура таблицы `charms`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `charms` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('health','power','protection') NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `power` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Структура второй таблицы

```
--
-- Структура таблицы `charms`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `charms` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('health','power','protection') NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `power` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `new` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: На кофейной гуще отвечающие гадать будут, как вы импорт выполняете? Код в вопрос добавьте. И структуру обеих таблиц.

Comment: все готово!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Так в первой таблице сначала поле `new` создайте аналогичное, а потом уже импортируйте данные из второй таблицы.

Comment: И че мне теперь постоянно по два раза создавать структуру, то есть и на локалке и на хосте? Я ведь на локалке хочу все делать, а потом так нормальненько перекидывать все на хост)

Comment: Логично, что если ты на локальном добавляешь или удаляешь столбцы/таблицы/индексы/прочее, то и на боевом надо изменять.... если ты хочешь это делать без постоянного ручного действия - копай в сторону миграций. Хотя все равно код для нее надо писать, так или иначе.

Comment: Программа `PhpMyAdmin` не обладает сведениями о версии базы данных и поэтому не может сказать, добавляли ли вы столбец или он был в таблице изначально. Поэтому она не генерирует код `ALTER TABLE ...`. Генерируемый код только пытается создать новую таблицу, если такой еще не существует и не умеет модифицировать уже существующую. Или ищите более специализированные средства, или пишите и сохраняйте скрипты на изменение.

Comment: вот оно как, всем спасибо, думаю этой информации будет достаточно, а то я тут с ума уже сходил.